# How to check Excel cell type,font,size and border in C#?

Tags: c#, excel

I finished main things in app I'm doing, but now I want know am I able to check cells type,font,size and border using C# while I'm iterating trough the cells, so when I "copy" values to another Excel document I can use those parameters on the cell that im placing value in?

This is how I read/write from one Excel to another:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application polazniExcel = new 
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
polazniExcel.FileValidation = MsoFileValidationMode.msoFileValidationSkip;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook polazna = 
polazniExcel.Workbooks.Open(textBoxPolazna.Text.ToString());
Excel.Worksheet Polazni = polazniExcel.Sheets[1];//sheet koji treba unijeti 


Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application krajnjiExcel = new 
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
krajnjiExcel.FileValidation = MsoFileValidationMode.msoFileValidationSkip;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook krajnja = 
krajnjiExcel.Workbooks.Open(textBoxKrajnja.Text.ToString());
Excel.Worksheet Krajnji_PoMT = krajnjiExcel.Sheets["Po mjestu troška"];//sheet po mjestu troska
Excel.Worksheet Krajnji_Ukupno = krajnjiExcel.Sheets["Ukupno po mjesecima"];//sheet ukupno


Excel.Range brojRedovaPolazni = Polazni.UsedRange;
int brojacRedovaPolazni = brojRedovaPolazni.Rows.Count; //broj redova u polaznom excelu 


Excel.Range brojRedovaKrajnjiMT = Krajnji_PoMT.UsedRange;
int brojacRedovaKrajnjiMT = brojRedovaKrajnjiMT.Rows.Count;//broj redova u krajnjem excelu sheet mjesto troska

Excel.Range brojRedovaKrajnjiUkupno = Krajnji_Ukupno.UsedRange;
int brojacRedovaKrajnjiUkupno = brojRedovaKrajnjiUkupno.Rows.Count;//broj redova u krajnjem excelu sheet ukupno

for (int x = 1; x <= brojacRedovaKrajnjiMT - 12; x++)
{            
 string cellValue = "";
 object rangeObject = Polazni.Cells[x+12, kolumna];
 Excel.Range xx = (Excel.Range)rangeObject;
 object rangeValue = xx.Value2;
 if(rangeValue!=null)
 {
  cellValue= rangeValue.ToString();
 }else
 {
  cellValue = null;
 }

 Krajnji_PoMT.Cells[(x + 12), kolumna_broj].Value2 = cellValue;
}
```

brojacRedovaKrajnjiMT - 12 because 1st 12 rows are just a title, and "kolumna" represents number of column inside that sheet.

Comment: How are you iterating through the cells? With OpenXML, ClosedXML, interop? Can you provide details and share what you have done

Comment: Best way of doing this depends on context of the copying. Are there formulas, are there conditional formats etc? You could have two lines of code, 1 that copies values, and one that copies formats.

Comment: @FortyTwo I edited, there the code for it.

Comment: @MacroMarc I like ur idea, just tell me how to copy formats haha